# Proof of Unique factorization in Dedekind Rings .

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Proof de unique factorizaation in Dedekind Rings. Algebraic Number fields, Janusz, Second edition.
[image]

In the above proof, Theorem 3.13.

Why of the corolary 3.7, $\mathfrak{p}_1^{b_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{b_n}\subseteq \mathcal{U}$  ?

I don´t understand this part of the theorem.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is $\overline{\frak p}_1,\dots,\overline{\frak p}_n$ are all of the prime ideals in $R/\frak U$, and they correspond to prime ideals $\frak p_1, \dots, \frak p_n$ in $R$.  Now by the corollary there are $b_1,\dots,b_n$ such that ${\overline{\frak p}_1}^{b_1}\cdots{\overline{\frak p}_n}^{b_n}$ equals the zero ideal in $R/\frak U$ (if some $b_i$'s are zero just multiply both sides by $\frak p_1, \dots, \frak p_n$ to make sure they are all positive).  Now ${\overline{\frak p}_1}^{b_1}\cdots{\overline{\frak p}_n}^{b_n}=(0)$ in $R/\frak U$ $\Rightarrow$ ${\frak p}_1^{b_1}\cdots{\frak p}_n^{b_n}\subseteq \frak U$ in $R$.

Comment: Thaks, Gregory Grant. 1) But, ${\overline{\frak p}_1}^{b_1}\cdots{\overline{\frak p}_n}^{b_n}=(0)$ not implies that   ${\frak p}_1^{b_1}\cdots{\frak p}_n^{b_n}=\frak U$ ?

2) Why the ideals in the corolary  3.7 are exactly  the ideals $\mathfrak{p}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{p}_n$?

Comment: They are exactly those ideals because if any are missing you can multiply both sides by $\overline{\frak p_1},\dots,\overline{\frak p_n}$ to raise all exponents to be positive.

Comment: there is no ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ in this product  distinct of the ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$?

Comment: I don't understand, where is $\frak q$ coming from now?

Comment: The step of multiplying both sides by $\frak p_1\dots\frak p_n$ to make sure all exponents are positive is what can make the product be a subset of $\frak U$ and not necessarily equal to it.

Comment: I understand, thank you.